# Are those cheap ANYCUBIC 3D printers worth it's money?

Tags: print-quality

I would need a simple 3D printer for small 3D objects. I have seen that for example ANYCUBIC has very cheap ones. Are they worth it's money?

Comment: This question is too vague (which printing process are you hinting to: FFF, SLA?), furthermore, this is very subjective.

Comment: likely to get opinions as answers.  how cheap can you get them? it may be worth it just to have a toy to learn with before moving on to something slightly more robust.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I have heard from a friend using Anycubic printers is that they are good for the money. They claim that the printers are reliable and rarely get any faults in them. Some cheaper printers may not have the most up-to-date spec however if you're going to be doing just basic printing then I'm pretty sure it'll be good enough to get you going. The budget here isn't clear however my current printer for the last 2 years has been the Creality Ender 3 Pro. It is an extremely good printer for the money (around $200) and has everything to get you going as well as being fully upgradeable if you are into that and I personally would argue this is as good as you can get for the money.